# Is there a way to save a bitmap from the debug console in Android Studio (Intellij)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In android studio you can view bitmaps from the debug console by clicking next to the variable (view bitmap). I was wondering if there was a way to save these to the computer your working on?
[image: Bitmap I'm trying to save]

Comment: I am afraid the only solution is to save it locally then `adb pull` or something transfer client-server-ly to computer.

Comment: try this https://gist.github.com/vxhviet/07429133e71b5fec2e39bd60171184cd

Comment: @GenoChen, I also think it is possible to store bitmap using adb command on terminal. If so can you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: @XueQing What do you mean of "store bitmap using adb command"?

Comment: @GenoChen, Ah, I think I confused something. So what you said was that you can get bitmap files stored locally through the adb command after saving.

Comment: @XueQing No, what I mean "locally" there means "inside the phone". That is, save it in the phone first, then `adb pull` to computer.

Answer (score 2):

there is the possibility to evaluate code, when having the execution halted at a break-point, which permits pasting code into there, which may then perform the export by given `Bitmap` handle ... assuming the active application has already been granted permission to write to external storage.

this would be the code to paste and evaluate, where `bitmap` is the handle to export:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "test.jpg"));
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
    output.flush();
    output.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and this is how it should look alike:

[image: evaluate code]

the exported image can then be downloaded with the "Device File Explorer" from `/mnt/sdcard`.